# Codeigniter: how to serve static html pages in codeigniter context

Tags: codeigniter

Hi all
I want to serve some static html pages in codeigniter context. I dont want to bypass the index.php file in the base_url.
But when I user the call to the HTML file, it dispays the 404 error page.
I appreciate any help for this topic from guys who already solving this problem . Thanks for all in advance

I want to precise this elements:

1. my real problem is to serve PDF file for users to display in the browser only an not to save the PDF file. So I convert the PDF to HTML Files.  The output is a directory with HTML files linked  betwen them and ther images/button, CSS, js for navigation
2. when i put this HTML-OUTPUT in  ci\Docs\HTML1 directory I can access it whith this URL localhost/ci/docs/html1/index.htm.
   But where i use  localhost/ci/index.php/docs/html1/index.htm I get A 404 error page.
3. So I moved The HMLT1 directory to the Application\views directory. And i stil have the same error. My .htacces look like this:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 

   </IfModule>
   ```

Thanks Guys for your help

Comment: Are you using a .htaccess file? If so, what does it look like? Where in your Codeigniter project are your static html files stored? Via which URL do you want to access them?

Comment: Give us some information about your existing structure.

Answer (score 12):

Create the static HTML file as a view and then just load the view:

```
$this->load->view('static.html');
```

You can then access this file as a normal controller. It all depends on how you have set up your .htaccess as well.

Comment: I add the asked element in my question

Answer (score 1):

For me I just add a folder name for my static html pages into the .htaccess to exclude it from regexp like below, and it work. Just to exclude it from rewrite URL to index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|static-html) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

$route['your-page-url'] = "/page/message/your-page-url";

In your Page controller function:

```
public function message($page = 'your-page-url')
{
    $data['title']= 'Your Page Title';
    $this->load->view('/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('pages/your-page-url');
    $this->load->view('/footer');
}
```